# I have a few errors in android that I do not understand, how do I fix them?

Tags: android, android-studio

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

public MainActivity(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
}


 private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if     (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}

public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.Open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return c;
}
```

}
 I am having trouble with errors like when I type

```
public MainActivity(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
```

It says that "Activity() in Activity can not be applied to (android.Context.context.)"

And also when I type

```
public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.Open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return c;
}
```

It says:
"Cannot resolve method .Open"
Which from my research Camera.Open() is a method.

Comment: Please check the android developer site https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Activities are instantiated by the operating system, so there's no reason you build a constructor. Beside this, Activity does not have a constructor with parameters, so you cannot call super(some_object).

Camera class does not have a static method Open(). It does not have static methods at all...

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: So what should I do instead?

Comment: If you want to take pictures, I suggest you to read this document from Google [link](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/index.html). There are simple examples and you can also download sample code.

For the answer about the activity, this document from Google is a must read [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).